# Series.agg() works differently when passing function

Tags: pandas, series

Called a Function inside agg() of Series, from below snippet of code, in first call it's printing int number for variable "a", and in second call it's coming as Series. I am not able to figure it out the reason for this behaviour.

```
 import pandas as pd
    ser = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
    def find_second_last(a):
        print(a)
        return a.iloc[-2]
    ser.agg(find_second_last)
```

Answer (score 0):

`.iloc` with single position without `[]` will return the `int` by default

```
a.iloc[[-2]]# return pd.Series
a.iloc[-2] # return int
a.iloc[1:] # return pd.Series
```

Comment: Thank you, Could you please explain why in first call of find_second_last giving "a" as 1 and in second call it's giving Series. not able to understand how find_second_last call is performed.

Comment: @SwamiViswanadh first is print the input variable which is series , 2nd is to select the single value return,1st equal to print(ser)